# Python Mulitprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm currently experimenting with multiprocessing in Python, and I've made this small script:

```
import multiprocessing, time

def test_def():
        time.sleep(5)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_def())
print p, p.is_alive()
```

Yet, when I run it, it waits 5 secondes before it prints out:

```
<Process(Process-1, initial)> False
```

To me, this makes little sense. If p.start() isn't called, then how can the function be running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_def())
```

you actually call the function. The correct way, per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class), would be

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_def)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `target=` keyword expects a *function* to be called in the new process.
You are effectively passing it `None` since you have written `target=test_def()` and not `target=test_def`. The former gives the return value of your `test_def()` function after calling it (which is `None`).

You are also never actually *starting*  your process, so you need to add a `p.start()` and `p.join()` as well.